# New to front-end and don't know how to add bootstrap to project

Tags: bootstrap-4, frontend

It is said:

```
CSS
Copy-paste the stylesheet <link> into your <head> before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I don't know which file to add the line in the project:

[image: project structure]

Comment: Exactly where it says, into the `<head>` tag, which is in the HTML. If you've not yet created a file for the HTML, then there is nowhere to paste it at the moment.

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] of your project (on codesandbox.io or similar). We have no way of knowing what's inside those folders and how your project serves/builds from a screenshot of the project root.